# Equivalent of using && in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database (let's say t1 and t2) and I have a field of type BIT in each table (let's call it field1), what I want to do is have the same functionality obtained by using the && boolean operator (like in C, C#, Java .. etc), or in other words I want to do this:

select t1.field1 && t2.field1 from t1, t2 where ..
(if field1 is false in one of the tables, it should return false, to return true it has to be true in both tables)

I know it can be done with a use case (or IF() in MySQL), but I'm curious to know if there are other ways ...

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.field & t2.field
```

Comment: This is wrong. Example SELECT 2&4 returns 0 when it should return true

Comment: Ya but if 0 or non zero is seen as false or true, then I could see how this would eventually lead to a bug.  But I agree if you are for sure only using a BIT field it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.field1 && t2.field1 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.field1 = 1 AND t2.field2 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AND` and `&&`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) are equivalent. So you can either use “`t1.field1 && t2.field1`” or “`t1.field1 AND t2.field1`”:

```
SELECT t1.field1 && t2.field1
FROM …

SELECT t1.field1 AND t2.field1
FROM …
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard SQL way to do it - any such mechanism is DBMS-specific.

Comment: post is tagged mysql, so question is DMBS specific